# Phantom 1px border only in safari on hover animation

Tags: html, css, safari

For some reason, during the zoom animation on the two column sections on http://hush.superfame.us/homepage/team/ I'm seeing a 1px border that doesn't show before or after an animation, but just during. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, I didn't notice any kind of border appearing during the animation.

Comment: Thanks for checking, it's only visible on Safari. If you look at the center line between two of the profiles and go over the middle  edge left to right or back you'll see a 1px border